How to apply viewMatrix value directly to camera in three.js?
I'm synchronizing two objects from different browsers, aiming to synchronize the viewMatrix value for panning purposes using websocket.
Based on chatGPT
camera.matrixWorldInverse.copy(viewMatrix);

It should work, but in fact, it didn't. Is there another way to apply the viewMatrix to the camera's matrixWorldInverse?
When I do console.log, the camera.matrixWorldInverse or the camera.matrixWorld - nothing has changed....
I have also tried
    camera.matrixWorldInverse.copy(viewMatrix);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

and
    camera.matrixWorldInverse.copy(viewMatrix);
    camera.matrixWorld.copy(viewMatrix.clone().invert());
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

neither of these worked for me....
Can anyone please help me?
